# Android: Replace soft keyboard with custom layout (Wheels for date picking)

Tags: android, android-widget

I have a `EditText` where user needs to enter date. For date picking I have a custom wheel view (like iOS). Now on click of `date EditText`, I want to open a soft keyboard like drawer from bottom & put that wheel view inside it.

So can I replace the soft keyboard with my wheel view ? I mean, the `container` which hold the keyboard should now hold my custom `wheel view`.

Is there any way to achieve that ? Or any other better option for my purpose ?

Answer (score 1):

1) If you must use `EditText`, you can prevent keyboard coming up, by setting its input type correctly. Other answer already mentions that.

2) But why use `EditText` here, especially since you are not inputing any value using keyboard here.  You can use a `TextView`, and its `onClickListener` you can animate a `LinearLayout` (containing date picker) upwards.

```
yourTextView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
        //Animate a LinearLayout containing a DatePicker
        animateDatePickerView();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your requirements and how re-usable you want it to be.

For the simple way, you can create a view to host that wheel picker align it bottom of the root layout and just hide/show it with some animation.

First you would want to override the onTouchListener of your edit text, consume the event and do what you want there.

```
editText.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    public boolean onTouch (View v, MotionEvent event) {
        //Show the wheely wheel.
        return true; //Consume the event.
    }
 });
```

Comment: Through hide/show or animation, I need to overlap it on existing layout. Any good tutorial known to you for this purpose ?

Comment: You have many options. You can add your datePicker layout to your contentView, if it is relative layout or FrameLayout. You can't use LinearLayout in that case, since it doesn't support z-axis alignment.

Comment: Or you can use [popupWindow](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html). I never used it before, so I don't know how much customization is possible.

Answer (score 0):

My personal idea (not tested)

- prevent showing keyboard when edittext is focused.
  E.g, `setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);`
- Use a customized activity which contains your wheel and show it as dialog ( set theme as dialog).